# How to integrate signal app with ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

How to integrate signal app with ASP.NET MVC?

I have a requirement to send an attachment user's signal app from an ASP.NET MVC application.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [danadarras](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15032836) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66845221) saying "It depends on the type of attachment you would like to integrate, but you can refer to the link below for guiding steps. [https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224689/SignalR-Chat-App-With-ASP-NET-WebForm-And-BootSt-2](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1224689/SignalR-Chat-App-With-ASP-NET-WebForm-And-BootSt-2)"

Comment: hi, found any solution?. I doubt you meant signal messenger integration